# Iterating over a custom hashtable

Tags: java, loops, iterator, iteration, hashtable

I have a custom hashtable implementation in java.

```
public class HashSet<T> implements HashTableInterface<T> {

private static int DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE = 10;

private T[] items;

public HashSet() {
    final T[] items = (T[]) new Object[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE];
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public boolean add(T item) {
    int index = getIndex(item);
    do {
        if (items[index] != null) {
            index = (index + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        } else {
            items[index] = item;
            break;
        }
    } while (index != getIndex(item));

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean remove(T item) {
    if (contains(item)) {
        items[getIndex(item)] = null;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean contains(T item) {
    T itemArray = items[getIndex(item)];
    if (item.equals(itemArray)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int index = (getIndex(item) + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        do {
            if (items[index] != null) {
                if (items[index].equals(item)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    index = (index + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (index != getIndex(item));
    }
    return items[getIndex(item)] != null;
}

@Override
public int getIndex(T item) {
    return item.hashCode() % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    for (T item : items) {
        if (item != null) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return items.toString();
}}
```

In my add method I want to check if the place where the item would be stored is free, if not it should go to the next index. Until it finds an empty place.

My code works but I think, there could be a better way to do this.

```
public boolean add(T item) {
    int index = getIndex(item);
    do {
        if (items[index] != null) {
            index = (index + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        } else {
            items[index] = item;
            break;
        }
    } while (index != getIndex(item));

    return true;
}
```

I have the same problem in the contains method

```
public boolean contains(T item) {
    T itemArray = items[getIndex(item)];
    if (item.equals(itemArray)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int index = (getIndex(item) + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
        do {
            if (items[index] != null) {
                if (items[index].equals(item)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    index = (index + 1) % DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (index != getIndex(item));
    }
    return items[getIndex(item)] != null;
}
```

Comment: Your class is not a Set. When encountered "duplicate" item, it overwrites the another item in its contents, and keeps both the original and its duplicate.

Comment: When a duplicate item, with the same hashvalue but different value will be added, it should add them. But just at the next free place.

Comment: Your remove method is bugged and will remove the first entry which has the same hashcode as the element you actually want to remove. Also it makes it impossible to find the other elements again.

Comment: @Fabian, then as I said, this class is not a Set, beause adding a duplicate to set does nothing, whereas adding to your data structure replaces a completely unrelated item.

Comment: @kutschkem yes, I'm it's still in development.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no it's not a Set as you know it but it doesn't replace anything, it places an item at a **free** place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a many different ways to do collision avoidance, what you did is called "Linear Probing".

There is also (reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing))

Quadratic probing

[image: H+1^{2},H+2^{2},H+3^{2},H+4^{2},...,H+k^{2}]

Double hashing

[image: h(i,k) = ( h_1(k) + i \cdot h_2(k) ) mod|T|.]

And schemes that use linked lists for colliding values.

All of these have different tradeoffs which you should inform yourself on to make an informed decision.